# Get previous elements in circular slider

Tags: jquery, css

[image]
 I have an image slider where by clicking an image I want to get all previous image elements IDs, which are written on html page. When I try to print all *previous Elements* all `img` are printed because of circular div .
For example, if I click on image #5, I want to get only 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Now below code returns 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, and so on.

```
var ids = t.prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1').map(function(){
  return this.id;
}).get().join();

console.log(ids);

$(document).ready(function () {

/*   Reading the data from XML file*/

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "photos.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
      var path = $(this).attr('path');
      var width = $(this).attr('width');
      var height = $(this).attr('height');
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
      var longdesc = $(this).find('longdesc').text();
      var description = $(this).find('desc').text();
      $('#myImageFlow').append('<img src="'+path+'" id='+id+'  height="'+height+'"  width="'+ width+'" longdesc="'+longdesc+'" alt="'+alt+'"/>');
      imgArr[i] = description;
      imgFront[i]=longdesc;                 
      backimg[i]=longdesc;
      frontimg[i]=path;
      i = i+1;  
    });
```

Comment: What's `t`? Can you make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ Dogbert t=$(this) ... any clicked image

Comment: Is that the actual complete code? You haven't assigned anything to `t`

Comment: @ Dogbert assign what ?